# Root my EVO wihtout USB cord

Tags: rooting, htc-evo

I want to root my EVO... but my charging port is broken (I've been using an external battery charger to get around this). Anyway to get the files I need to root my EVO onto my EVO without using this cable? I was thinking about going through Box or Dropbox or something like that but I'm not sure how to download these files into a specific folder on my EVO.

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible but I have to advise against this. If something goes wrong you will not be able to repair it without USB connection.

Comment: You can use unrEVOked root exploiter app: http://androidspin.com/2010/06/05/unrevoked-one-click-root-evo-4g-cdma-hero/ But, the apk file has been officially removed. Search the web for this apk file.. Good luck!

Comment: there is no way to backup my phone on an SD card or anything so that if something does go wrong, I can just pull it off the card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always put the files on an SD card and transfer them to your internal storage from there, but as was said in the comments, if something happens during the process and you are unable to boot your phone, the only way to recover from that is to reflash it from the computer, using the usb cable. You can use Titanium Backup to back all of your apps up onto the SD card, and hopefully you keep everything you can backed up through Google, but you still would have an unusable phone if something happened.

Comment: cool thanks. in addition, will I be able to flash a custom ROM onto my phone without the USB cord?

Comment: Yes, so long as you have a way to put files on the phone (You can even download them straight to the phone), you don't need a computer unless you're changing the bootloaders (Such as going from 2.2 to 2.3/4.0) or if something goes wrong.